# How to create lambda from lambda with parameter without doing .call in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, lambda

I want to create a new lambda taking no arguments from lambda taking one.

Say, I have

```
irb(main):001:0> f1 = lambda { |p| p }
=> #<Proc:0x00000001045190@(irb):1 (lambda)>
irb(main):002:0> f1.call(2)
=> 2
```

and now I

```
irb(main):003:0> f2 = lambda { f1.call(2) }
=> #<Proc:0x00000000f620e8@(irb):3 (lambda)>
irb(main):004:0> f2.call
=> 2
```

but I do not want to create a lambda around first one but want to "substitute" parameter for it or something.

May be if we have `call`, there is some magic that do the same thing as call, but returns a lambda except of actually calling the code:

```
f2 = f1.some_magic(2)
f2.call
=> 2
```

P.S. Sorry if this question is dumb, this functional stuff is hard to understand to me sometimes.

P.P.S. Found [this topic](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/173699) on ruby-forum.com, and it seems I want to do the same things without unnecessary calls overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a function which binds the arguments to a proc.  This works with Ruby >= 1.8:

```
def bind_args(l, *bound_args)
  lambda { |*unbound_args|
    l[*(bound_args + unbound_args)]
  }
end
```

In use:

```
f1 = lambda { |p| p }   
f2 = bind_args(f1, 2)
p f2.call
# 2
```

If you want to bind some, but not all arguments, you can do that too:

```
f1 = lambda { |p, q| [p, q] }
f2 = bind_args(f1, 2)
p f2.call(3)
# [2, 3]
```

Except that `curry` makes a call rather than a new lambda if given the full arguments to the lambda being bound, this is pretty much what `curry` does.  I didn't call it `curry` to avoid confusion with the method of that name that's built into Ruby 1.9.

Comment: I think, this approach has the same problem. Tons of googling revealed [this topic](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/173699) which explains the problem (probably) better than me -- unnecessary calls to deeper levels of functions.

Comment: @asavartsov - If there's no other way to do it, aren't the nested lambdas necessary?

Comment: yeah, it seems that they are. I'll use your `bind_args` then, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for curry ?:

```
f1 = lambda { |p| p }
p f1.curry[2] #=> 2
```

Curry is available in Ruby 1.9

Comment: afaiu, curry[] executes code for last parameter instead of returning lambda.

Comment: That's because `f1` takes only 1 argument and as the docs say _"If a sufficient number of arguments are supplied, it passes the supplied arguments to the original proc and returns the result."_ If you e.g. call `curry` with one argument on a two argument `proc`/`lambda`, it does what you want.